# Does anyone know how to add an avatar to the Author shortcode in X theme for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, author

Trying to find where you add the image to the author shortcode in the xtheme the new wordpress theme

Answer (score 0):

It is not set within your WordPress site. What you need to do is create a [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com) account.

Just make sure you use the **same email address** to sign up for Gravatar as your WordPress account. It is then pulled in automatically.